# Query ACL graph using gremlin with parent hierarchy check

Tags: graph, acl, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

[my ACL graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUNR1.jpg)

In Summary every user or group who have access to Folder1 will have access to File1

**usecase #1** - checking access for user1 on Folder1, which works fine with below gremlin

```
g.V().has('user','userId','user1').
  emit().
    until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
    repeat(out('member_of')).
  filter(outE('has_permission').has('permission','VS_F').
           inV().has('folder','folderId','Folder1')).hasNext()
```

**usecase #2** - **checking access for user1 on File1, how can modify above gremlin to achieve this** ? im pretty much new to gremlin and doing a POC on janusgraph for my employer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: You should always start with a script that people can run to create your sample graph. Also, formatting the code in your question wouldn't hurt.

With that said, here's the script that creates your graph:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('user').property('userId','user1').as('u1').
  addV('user').property('userId','user2').as('u2').
  addV('user').property('userId','user3').as('u3').
  addV('group').property('groupId','group1').as('g1').
  addV('group').property('groupId','group2').as('g2').
  addV('group').property('groupId','group3').as('g3').
  addV('folder').property('folderId','folder1').as('f1').
  addV('file').property('fileId','file1').
  addE('in_folder').to('f1').
  addE('member_of').from('u1').to('g1').
  addE('member_of').from('u2').to('g2').
  addE('member_of').from('u3').to('g3').
  addE('member_of').from('g3').to('g1').
  addE('has_permission').from('g1').to('f1').
  addE('has_permission').from('u2').to('f1').iterate()
```

...and the query you're looking for:

```
g.V().has('file','fileId','file1').
  until(inE('has_permission')).
    repeat(out('in_folder')).as('folder').
  V().has('user','userId','user1').
  emit().
    until(__.not(outE('member_of'))).
    repeat(out('member_of')).
  filter(out('has_permission').where(eq('folder'))).hasNext()
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. and the comments will take care in my next post onward.

Comment: In the query you have posted, without 'where' clause the query is working. when i add the where clause it doesn't seems to be working. i'm using JanusGraphFactory to create graph and traverse. any comment on this ?

Comment: Elaborate on "not working". Do you get an error? I tested the query and it worked just fine.

Comment: Then something is not terminated properly, e.g. unbalanced parens or quotes.

Comment: will give a try again

Comment: Hi Daniel, When i use graph=TinkerGraph.open() the query works just fine. But when i use  graph=JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-cql-es-server.properties') it doesn't work. but without the where clause the desired result i'm getting.